# Prove that a $p$-adic integer $x$ is divisible by $p^n$ if and only if $x_n = 0$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let the ring of $p$-adic integers be the projective limit 
$$
\mathbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}}(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}),
$$
and denote an element $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a sequence $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}}$ with $x_n \in \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

I want to prove the following:

> An element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is divisible by $p^n$ if and only if $x_n=0$.

The implication to the right is clear. For the implication to the left, it is easily shown that $x_i$ is divisible by $p^n$ for all $i> 0$. Further, if $x_i=p^nx_i'$ for some $x_i'\in\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$ (and there may be multiple choices for such $x_i'$, since $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$ is not a domain) and $x'_j := (x'_i \bmod p^j)$ for $j<i$ we have that $p^j x_j' = x_j$. But there does not seem to be a way to construct a $p$-adic integer $x'$ such that $x'=p^nx$ from this: when increasing our index $i$ the choices of the previous elements $x_j'$ might change ad infinitum. With the approach I've taken so far, is there a way to finish the proof?

See *Serre, A Course in Arithmetic*, chapter II proposition 1, for a proof using a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatibility condition is crucial, so let’s get it on the board. You’re talking about sequences $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)$ such that: for each $m$, $x_m\in\Bbb Z/p^m\Bbb Z$ and $x_{m+1}\equiv x_m\pmod{p^m}$. Note that this condition also implies that for each $m$ and each $k\ge m$, $x_m\equiv x_k\pmod{p^m}$.

Let’s look at your problem now, in the special case that $n=2$. You have a sequence $(x_1,0,x_3,x_4,\cdots)$ satisfying compatibility. But $m=1$ says that $x_1\equiv0\pmod p$, so our sequence is actually $(0,0,x_3,x_4,\cdots)$. Furthermore, $m=2$ says that $x_3\equiv0\pmod{p^2}$, so it can be represented by $p^2\xi_3$ for $\xi_3\in\Bbb Z$, and indeed we can take $0\le\xi_3<p$. Similarly, $m=3$ says that $x_4\equiv x_2\pmod{p^2}$ and also that $x_4\equiv x_3\pmod{p^3}$. Thus $x_4=p^2\xi_4$  (where we can even take $0\le\xi_4<p^2$), and the congruence $p^2\xi_4\equiv p^2\xi_3\pmod{p^3}$ is equivalent to $\xi_3\equiv\xi_4\pmod p$. And so on.

I was going to go farther along these lines, but it seems to me that I’ve already answered your question. If not, I’ll be glad to amplify.

**Amplification**: I have made some changes in the text above, as an aid to the following:

The arguments above show that $\xi=(\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,\cdots)$ is a good element of $\Bbb Z_p$. I claim that the original $x=(0,0,x_3,x_4,\cdots)$ is equal to $p^2\xi$. Certainly, $p^2\xi=(p^2\xi_3,p^2\xi_4,p^2\xi_5,\cdots)$ with $p^2\xi_3\equiv0\pmod p$ and $p^2\xi_4\equiv0\pmod{p^2}$. What about the other coordinates? For $m\ge3$, the $m$-th coordinate of $p^2\xi$ is $p^2\xi_{m+2}=x_{m+2}\equiv x_m\pmod{p^m}$, and I think that that does it.

Comment: $x_3$ can be represented by $p^2\xi_3$ for many $\xi_3\in\mathbb{Z}$, but how do you pick the correct one so the compaibility conditions hold? Indeed, $p^2\xi_4\equiv p^2\xi_3 \pmod{p^3}$ is equivalent to $\xi_3\equiv\xi_4\pmod p$, but not to $\xi_3\equiv\xi_4\pmod{p^3}$, which is also required. (It is too late for me too think about this thoroughly, so forgive me if I'm talking rubbish. I'll look at it again tomorrow.)

Comment: I don't think $0\le\xi_3<p$ is always the correct choice. For example, consider $(0,0,4,4,20,20,...) \in\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is actually $2^2\cdot 5$, so $\xi_3 = 5$.

Comment: My recipe works fine in the case that $x$ starts $(0,0,4,4,\cdots)$ and is all $20$’s from then on. It gives $\xi_3=1$, $\xi_4=1$, all $5$’s from then on. So my $p$-adic integer is $(1,1,5,5,5,\cdots)$, and when you multiply this by $4$, you get $(0,0,4,4,20,20,\cdots)$. Don’t forget that the third entry is in $\Bbb Z/8$, the fourth in $\Bbb Z/16$, etc.

Comment: Please notice that I never claimed that $(0,0,\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,\cdots)$ was a $p$-adic integer. I only claimed that $(\xi_3,\xi_4,\xi_5,\cdots)$ is.

Comment: Ah yes, that's indeed what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

A $p$-adic integer is not *any* sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$, but it has to satisfy compatibility conditions:
$$x_n\bmod p^{n-1}=x_{n-1}.$$
Hence if $x_n\equiv 0\mod p^n$, $x_n\equiv 0\mod p^{n-1}. $

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I forgot the compatibility conditions, though I did not state explicitly which homomorphism are used in the projective limit definition.

Comment: OK, I'll remove ‘forgot’. With the compatibilty conditions, it is clearly true.

Comment: @Lubin: I just wanted to point why the indices start at $0$. I didn't mean to hurt anyone.

Comment: Sorry to be stupid, but it is not clear at all to me.

Comment: If $x$ is divisible by $p^n$, it is *a fortiori* divisible by $p^{n-1}$, don't you agree?

Comment: I agree but don't get what you mean: we want to prove that $x$ is divisible by $p^n$. I agree that $x_i=0$ for $0<i\leq n$, but I don't see how to construct a $p$-adic divisor of $x$.

Comment: @Lubin: It was a minor point. I'll remove my objection… Thanks for warning me about the change.

Comment: Concerning your removed objection: we would need a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}=\mathbf{0}$, so there was nothing wrong with my earlier definition. But I changed it to the more conventional one.